# How do I specify the left and right margins of buffers at a percentage, not a fixed value?

Tags: margins

I want to mainly margin only the left side, for example, to set the left margin to about 30% of the total width and 5% on the right side.

I'm using olivetti now but this package doesn't seem to be able to specify separately on the left and right. Is there any solution?

Comment: Is [this](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Shynur/tmp/main/pictures/2023-3-5-0.png) what you mean by margin?

Comment: It's probably set by built-in left-margin-width, your link is fringe? maybe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say just create a custom function for it e.g.:

```lisp
(defun set-window-margins-relatively (window left-fraction &optional right-fraction)
  (set-window-margins window
                      (round (* (window-width) left-fraction))
                      (when right-fraction
                        (round (* (window-width) right-fraction)))))
```

This function uses fractions (i.e. percentage/100) instead of percentage.

I haven't looked at Olivetti though (so I am not sure how it implemented things).

Comment: It worked perfectly as my purpose. Thanks!